# Trouble Using Zend-Framework on my shared hosting account

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a website... [imaspy.com](http://imaspy.com)... and I am having trouble using the Zend Framework I have uploaded to my hosting account.

Please go to my website and try to become a registered user (you can use fake information) and see the error that I receive. Here is the error:

> Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home/content/92/5336292/html/imaspy/scripts/library.php
>   on line 5
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php:mikerader.com/ZendFramework/library') in /home/content/92/5336292/html/imaspy/scripts/library.php on line 5

Here is the code I am using for library.php. (not the real password)

```
// Adjust the path to match the location of the library folder on your system
$library = 'mikerader.com/ZendFramework/library/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $library);
require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
try {
    Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $write = array('host'     => 'imaspy.db.5336292.hostedresource.com',
                   'username' => 'imaspy',
                   'password' => 'password123',
                   'dbname'   => 'imaspy');
    $read  = array('host'     => 'imaspy.db.5336292.hostedresource.com',
                   'username' => 'imaspy',
                   'password' => 'password123',
                   'dbname'   => 'imaspy');

    // Comment out the next two lines if using mysqli
    // and remove the comments from the last two lines
    $dbWrite = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($write);
    $dbRead = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($read);

    //$dbWrite = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli($write);
    //$dbRead = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli($read);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your bug:

```
$library = 'mikerader.com/ZendFramework/library/';
```

You need to use a path on the *server* not a URL. Something like:

```
$library = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/zend/library';
```

Or, provided you have the right permissions, an absolute path would work too:

```
// or wherever it is
$library = '/home/content/92/5336292/html/imaspy/library/Zend';
```

Also, why are you setting *two* db adapter objects like that when they're both identical?

Comment: it was a stupid thing for class. I'm just editing it to make it live. I am going to test out your solution and be right back.

Comment: Oh ok I understand. They're actually teaching Zend Framework at your school? Keep in mind that the paths I used are hypothetical, make sure you double check and use the correct one.

Comment: yes I got it working perfectly... thank you! Yes, the book we are using is teaching how to use the Zend Framework to setup user accounts on a website.

Comment: Nice that's cool, they picked a solid framework to use.  So why, again, are you creating _two_ instances of `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`? You know that you only need _one_ and you can read from and write to the database (depending on your db user's privileges of course) right?

Comment: yeah... I don't know much about this stuff. I have two set up because I set up two on my local host for some reason so I thought it would be easier to just keep it the same.

Answer (score 0):

in your php.ini

include_path = your local path to your zend library directory.

you probably don't have access to the php.ini,
however you can try doing it through your .htaccess file:

php_value include_path your local path to your zend library directory.